# Catching memory exception during recursive programming in Java Card

Tags: java, exception, recursion, smartcard, javacard

Although recursive programming style isn't recommended in Java Card, I want to make a little test on the Fibonacci algorithm. I wrote a function that compute the Fibonacci's suite for big integers (represented by byte arrays).

My code is the following:

```
public static byte[] fibonacci(byte[] n) {
    if (isLEThan1(n)) {
        return n;
    }
    else {
        return add(fibonacci(subtract(n, new byte[]{0x01})),fibonacci(subtract(n,new byte[]{0x02})));
    }
}
```

where `boolean isLEThan(byte[])` returns `true` if the integer represented by the byte array is less or equal than 1, `false` if not.

`byte[] add(byte[], byte[])` and `byte[] subtract(byte[], byte[])` implement addition and subtraction for big integers represented by byte arrays. They return a new byte array containing the result of the operation.

I thought that by giving a large array to the function described above, I will get an exception such as `SystemException.NO_RESOURCE` because of the number of array instantiated by subtract due to recursive calls.

But I have to think that I don't catch the right exception because I get `6F00` as status word.

Here's the list of exceptions that I consider:

```
try {
        fibonacci(array);
    } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
        ISOException.throwIt((short) 0x0100);
    } catch (ArrayStoreException e) {
        ISOException.throwIt((short) 0x0200);
    } catch (APDUException e) {
        ISOException.throwIt(Util.makeShort((byte) 0x03,
            (byte) e.getReason()));
    } catch (CryptoException e) {
        ISOException.throwIt(Util.makeShort((byte) 0x04,
            (byte) e.getReason()));
    } catch (ISOException e) {
        ISOException.throwIt(Util.makeShort((byte) 0x05,
            (byte) e.getReason()));
    } catch (PINException e) {
        ISOException.throwIt(Util.makeShort((byte) 0x06,
            (byte) e.getReason()));
    } catch (ServiceException e) {
        ISOException.throwIt(Util.makeShort((byte) 0x07,
            (byte) e.getReason()));
    } catch (SystemException e) {
        ISOException.throwIt(Util.makeShort((byte) 0x08,
            (byte) e.getReason()));
    } catch (TransactionException e) {
        ISOException.throwIt(Util.makeShort((byte) 0x09,
            (byte) e.getReason()));
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        ISOException.throwIt((short) 0x0A00);
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        ISOException.throwIt((short) 0x0B00);
    } catch (NegativeArraySizeException e) {
        ISOException.throwIt((short) 0x0C00);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        ISOException.throwIt((short) 0x0D00);
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        ISOException.throwIt((short) 0x0E00);
    }
    }
```

So, does somebody have an idea about the exception concerned in that case?

Comment: Needless to say, if you perform any kind of recursive calls on a system that usually has to cope with 8 KiB of memory *in total*, you're doing something wrong. Creating an array as output is equally bad on Java Card. Reconsider what you are learning by doing this. Recursive programming should not be necessary here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a `SystemException`. However, ISO/IEC 7816-4 doesn't allow you to use just any status word. Instead use e.g. `(short) (0x6700 | 0x0080 | e.getReason())` as reason for your `ISOException`.

Comment: Always "fun" when your error reporting code errors out. I'm still laughing about the "Error: Error lookup table not found" that I got from any error in a DOS program :)